# Is there a way to invoke a method if text field has crossed a specific limit?

Tags: flutter, post, textfield

I want to create post functionality like Facebook for my app when you are writing a post if your post length is less than 100 characters it shows a font size of 30 otherwise it turns back to 16. I know it can be achieved easily by checking if the length is less than 100 by using the changed method but using this approach you `setState(() {})` by every keystroke and it's super costly.

Comment: You can try using `auto_size_text_field`

Comment: it is not "super costly" at all - it is a normal solution in flutter world

Comment: also why would you need to call setState each keystroke? you would only have to call setState when the length goes above or below 100 characters

Comment: because you can only check if the current size is over or under 100 but you can't check if it has changed to become over or less than a 100. That's why setState would always be called no matter what.

Comment: no, you will call it only in two cases where length goes 100 -> 101 and when it goes from 101 -> 100, all you need is a previous value of that length stored as `int` in your custom `State` class

Comment: Yeah! all I needed to know was how to get previous value?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.